# Why is OpenAI image generation Api returning 400 bad request in Unity?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, post, openai-api, unitywebrequest

I'm testing out dynamically generating images using OpenAI API in Unity. Amusingly, I actually generated most of this code from chatGPT.

The Error response is: "Your request contained invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". But I cant see anything wrong with the json formatting of my requestbody...

I also found this other question which is probably failing for the same reason, whatever it is: [Why does Post request to OpenAI in Unity result in error 400?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72821522/why-does-post-request-to-openai-in-unity-result-in-error-400)

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Replace API_KEY with your actual API key
    private string API_KEY = "<api_key>";
    private string API_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations";

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetImage());
    }

    IEnumerator GetImage()
    {
        // Create a request body with the prompt "Player"
        string requestBody = "{\"prompt\": \"Player\",\"n\": 1,\"size\": \"128x128\"}";
        // Create a UnityWebRequest and set the request method to POST
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(API_URL, requestBody);

        // Set the authorization header with the API key
        www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + API_KEY);

        // Set the content type header
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Send the request
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        // Check for errors
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Apologies if it's something obvious, never made web requests in Unity before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnityWebRequests url-encodes content before submitting the request. This messes up the formatting. see: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1163204/prevent-unitywebrequestpost-from-url-encoding-the.html

using httpClient worked for me.